# C# Problems understanding and using a method that has a Func as part of a List<KeyValuePair> in it

Tags: c#, asp.net

It was suggested I use the following method:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<Client> OrderAndThenBy(IEnumerable<Client> list,  List<KeyValuePair<Func<Broker, object>, SortDirection>> sortInfo) {}
```

I know its returning IOrderedEnumerable by taking IEnumerable and iterating over "list".

Could someone explain the code `List<KeyValuePair<Func<Broker, object>, SortDirection>> sortInfo` and how to iterate over it using the KeyValuePair in this method.

Finally how would you use this ie how would you call it?

EDIT.. in response to Daniels concerns.. This is a situation where the list is a keyValue pair that holds anywhere up to 4 items to sort by where the first item is orderby and the rest are thenby. The key in the value pair is the column to be sorted and the value is the sort direction. I dont know how few or how many columns will be sorted or.. which direction they will be either.. hence the ugliness.. I further wanted to make this a generic function to not have the same function rewritten several times..

I'd be glad if someone suggested a way to do this elegantly..

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how *not* to design a method. It would be a lot clearer and simpler to use the LINQ methods, `OrderBy` or `OrderByAscending`, followed by `ThenBy` or `ThenByAscending`. As extension methods that chain onto the previous expression, these avoid you having to explicitly construct an ugly `List` type, leaving your code much more readable.

So I'd suggest you try that, and you should get `OrderAndThenBy` removed from your codebase!

Answer (score 1):

You would call it by passing a map of the property to sort by and the direction to sort:

```
var orderedList = OrderAndThenBy(someList, new List<KeyValuePair<Func<Broker, object>, SortDirection>>(){
    {broker => broker.SomeProperty, SortDirection.Ascending},
    {broker => broker.SomeOtherProperty, SortDirection.Descending}
});
```

Then you can iterate the result as normal....

```
foreach(var item in orderedList){
   // Do something with item
}
```